# Pixate box-shadow not appearing

Tags: android, css, pixate

My android app places a "hovering controls" view hovering on top of the main view.  The view is used to contain a set of controls and this should have an outset shadow (in fact any shadow is a good starting point).

I have tried with no success in setting this up and would appreciate any help.

My default.css looks something like this:

```
#myHoveringControl {
    background-color    : #FFFFFF;
    border              : 1px solid black;
    box-shadow          : 0 8pc 8px #777;
}
```

The background-color and border are working fine so I know the styling is working and the style ID is correct, but the box-shadow seems to do nothing.

(P.S. I am using Xamarin, however, I don't see this as relevant except for any code samples if required)